What does the ! do in dart
_firestore.collection('users').doc(userCredential.user!.uid).set({

In this line, what does the ! next to user do - This is with dart and firestore
I'm just curious and want to know what it does from the tutorial I'm watching. Anything would be helpful, thanks!

The ! symbol is used to assert that a nullable variable indeed has a non-null value at runtime. It tells the Dart compiler that you know the variable is not null, even if it's nullable. If the variable is null when you use the ! operator, it will result in a runtime exception.     It’s essential to be cautious when using the ! operator since it bypasses the null safety check and can lead to crashes if the variable is actually null.
